# Loading Bitmaps Efficiently

Tags: java, android, image

Suppose there is a huge bitmap, `huge_bitmap`, in the `drawable-nodpi` folder. I want to create a custom view with `huge_bitmap` as its background:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Bitmap mBackground;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        mBackground = decodeAndResizeFromResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.huge_bitmap, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

where `decodeAndResizeFromResource` method subsamples the image and loads a smaller, scaled version into memory.

This works fine. However, `onMeasure` will often be invoked more than once. Lint warns about this:

> Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)

Allocating objects in methods such as `onMeasure`, `onLayout`, `onSizeChanged` and `onDraw` should therefore be avoided.

*How do I correctly fix the example above?*

I obviously don’t want to preallocate the bitmap (assume it will throw an `OutOfMemoryError`). Since I need the view’s measured width and height in order to subsample/scale accordingly, I need to load the bitmap after measuring.

Here are two possible workarounds:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBackground == null) {
        mBackground = decodeAndResizeFromResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.huge_bitmap, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, mPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

or maybe

```
private int mWidth, mHeight;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int w = getMeasuredWidth();
    final int h = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (mWidth != w || mHeight != h) {
        mBackground = decodeAndResizeFromResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.huge_bitmap, w, h);
        mWidth = w;
        mHeight = h;
    }
}
```

but both feel clumsy. What would you recommend?

Comment: If you do `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.huge_bitmap);` in the Activity's `onResume` method, doesn't Android take care of the scaling itself?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It does. However, it loads a full image into memory (without subsampling). As written in the post, assume this throws an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that the first thing for me would be to move your logic away from the view in a [MVP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) way.

With that in place you could use a observer/observable pattern to wrap that logic in a different class that would be triggered when that event happen.

The problem with this is when your `onMeasure` is triggered before the `addObserver` is ran, this of course would end up with the `decodeAndResizeFromResource()` not running on that first call. A way to fix that, if it is an issue, could be using `CustomPresenter` constructor to make the values manually or use some default values and make that first call.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class CustomPresenter extends View implements Observable {

    private Bitmap mBackground;
    private List observers = new ArrayList();

    public CustomPresenter (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPresenter (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomPresenter (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        hasChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public Map getHugeBitmap(){
        return this.drawable.huge_bitmap;
    }

    public void registerObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer ob : observers) {
            ob.update(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the "View"

```
    public class CustomResizerView implements Observer{
       public void update(Object obj){
           CustomPresenter view = (CustomPresenter) obj;            
           mBackground = decodeAndResizeFromResource(view.getResources(),
                   view.getHugeBitmap, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
       }
}
```

Then the test

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CustomPresenter view = new CustomPresenter();
        CustomResizerView resizer = new CustomResizerView();
        view.registerObserver(resizer);
    }
}
```